# calculating the O notation for block of code

Tags: c++, data-structures

[code of calculating O notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSshK.png)

as Sequential loops are added so it should be n*log(n)+n
 but as Only the largest term is kept, all others are dropped then it may be 
 n*log(n)
 so what isthe O notation for the block n*log(n)+n or n*log(n)

here is the code

```
{
    for(int m = 0; m < 2*n; m++) //O(n)
       {
           cout << m << endl;

        }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)//O(n*log(n))
       { 
           for(int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2){

             //do_constant time stuff;

        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: {
for(int m = 0; m < 2*n; m++) //O(n)
{
    cout << m << endl;

}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)//O(n*log(n))
 { 
    for(int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2){

        //do_constant time stuff;

    }

}
}

Comment: As you can see, code looks like jumbled garbage in comments. I recommend editing the question to remove the image and replace it with the code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have the code directly in it, as text, with proper formating. And do you know what the asymptotic complexity (big-O notation) actually means? Are you aware that if a function is `O(n*log (n) + n)`, it is also `O(n*log(n))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, you need to understand what the big-O notation actually means. If a function `f(n)` is `O(g(n))`, it means that there is a constant `c` such that from a certain `n0` onwards, `f(n) < c*g(n)`.

In programming, the function in question is usually the time (or space) complexity of the program.

From the definition, you can show that when your time complexity is `O(n*log(n) + n)`, it is also `O(n*log(n))`, because `f(n) = n * log(n) + n` is `O(n * log(n))`. Proof:

Define `f(n) = n * log(n) + n`. Let's analyse the required inequality:

```
n * log(n) + n < c * n * log(n)

               n < (c - 1) * n * log(n)
```

When `n > 2`, `log(n) > 1`. Therefore, if we take `c > 2` and `n > 2`, the right-hand side contains `n` multiplied by two terms greater than 1, so it's trivially larger than `n`.

Therefore, each function `O(n * log(n) + n)` is also `O(n * log(n))`. The standard form of big-O notation is to drop unnecessary terms, so the code's complexity is `O(n * log(n))`.